# changing navbar icons to active with django-Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I have made a navbar with bootstrap4 and I want to toggle the icon of current page to active.
Currently, I am using

```
<li class="nav-item"><a href="/" id="A"
                      {% if request.path == "/" %}
                        class="nav-link active" 
                      {% else %}
                        class="nav-link"
                      {% endif %}>Home</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a href="/blog" id="B"
                     {% if request.path == "/blog/" %}
                     class="nav-link active" {% else %}
                     class="nav-link"
                     {% endif %}>Blog</a></li>
```

what I would like is a simpler way with use of url names that could activate a script
like this:

```
{% if request.path == '/' %}
<script>
document.getElementById("#A").classList.add('active');
if ( document.getElementById("#A").classList.contains('active') )
document.getElementById("#A").classList.toggle('active');
</script>

{% elif request.path == '/blog/' %}
<script>
document.getElementById("#B").classList.add('active');
if ( document.getElementById("#B").classList.contains('active') )
document.getElementById("#B").classList.toggle('active');
</script>
{% endif %}
```

Could there be an easier way? Please suggest to highlight the active page icon on navbar to toggle styles.
Thank you

Comment: Your first method is less verbose, more readable and initiates server-side - it's actually better. Why do want to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this without violating DRY principles and hard-coding your urls would be to use `reverse` in the templates.

Example:

```
<!-- Top of page (below extends and include) -->
{% url 'index' as index %}
{% url 'blog' as blog %}

<!-- ..... Body HTML ..... -->

<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="{{ index }}" id="A" class="nav-link {% if request.path == index %}active{% endif %}">
        Home
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="{{ blog }}" id="B" class="nav-link {% if request.path == blog %}active{% endif %}">
        Blog
    </a>
</li>
```